# Default encoding for variant bstr to std::string conversion

Tags: c++, com, msxml, std

I have a variant bstr that was pulled from MSXML DOM, so it is in UTF-16. I'm trying to figure out what default encoding occurs with this conversion:

```
VARIANT vtNodeValue;
pNode->get_nodeValue(&vtNodeValue);
string strValue = (char*)_bstr_t(vtNodeValue);
```

From testing, I believe that the default encoding is either Windows-1252 or Ascii, but am not sure.

Btw, this is the chunk of code that I am fixing and converting the variant to a wstring and going to a multi-byte encoding with a call to WideCharToMultiByte.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `operator char*` method calls `_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString()`.  [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6(v=vs.140).aspx) is pretty unhelpful, but I assume it uses the current locale settings to do the conversion.

Update:

Internally, `_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString()` calls `WideCharToMultiByte`, passing zero for all the code-page and default character parameters.  This is the same as passing `CP_ACP`, which means to use the system's current ANSI code-page setting (not the current thread setting).

If you want to avoid losing data, you should probably call `WideCharToMultiByte` directly and use `CP_UTF8`.  You can still treat the string as a null-terminated single-byte string and use `std::string`, you just can't treat bytes as characters.

Comment: Thanks!!!

The default code page on US Windows is 1252, which is consistent with what I have observed. This can be determined on any machine with this call:
 int nCodePage=GetACP();

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` by itself doesn't specify/contain any encoding. It is merely a sequence of bytes. The same holds for `std::wstring`, which is merely a sequence of `wchar_t`s (double-byte words, on Win32).

By converting `_bstr_t` to a `char*` through its [operator char*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb(VS.71).aspx), you'll simply get a pointer to the raw data. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx), this data consists of wide characters, that is, `wchar_t`s, which represent UTF-16.

I'm surprised that it actually works to construct a `std::string` from this; you should not get past the first zero byte (which occurs soon, if your original string is English).

But since `wstring` is a string of `wchar_t`, you should be able to construct one directly from the `_bstr_t`, as follows:

```
_bstr_t tmp(vtNodeValue);
wstring strValue((wchar_t*)tmp, tmp.length());
```

(I'm not sure about `length`; is it the number of bytes or the number of characters?) Then, you'll have a `wstring` that's encoded in UTF-16 on which you can call `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: That's not right, it's not really a cast, `bstr_t` has an `operator char*` defined which does conversion internally.

Comment: I know. Is the word "cast" inappropriate? Maybe "conversion operator" is better. I'll change it.

Comment: That is incorrect: casting a `_bstr_t` to `char*` calls the `_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString` function to convert the string to a byte-based encoding.

Comment: I guess you can call it a cast, but you're definitely not just getting a pointer to the wide-char data.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb(VS.71).aspx : "These operators can be used to extract raw pointers to the encapsulated Unicode or multibyte BSTR object. The operators return the pointer to the actual internal buffer, so the resulting string cannot be modified."
No mention of any conversion. Is MSDN wrong?

Comment: @Thomas I suspect the intent of that statement was to indicate that you do not need to deallocate the result.  What that statement doesn't say but only implies is that there are actually *two* internal buffers.  (Actually rather confusing considering they say "the" pointer to "the" internal buffer.)  You get a different pointer value, not just a differently-typed pointer to the same address, depending on what operator you use.  The fact that there are both wide and narrow buffers further implies that `bstr_t` must be doing internal encoding conversions.